# How to get all the users from an specific role

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I got my `Users` which is divided into two categories: `Student` and `Professor`, I'm trying to get all of the users within the `Professor` role, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is the code wherein I try to do that:

```
RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
List<IdentityUserRole> professors = roleManager.FindByName("Professor").Users.ToList();

List<AppUser> users = new List<AppUser>();

foreach(IdentityUserRole iuser in professors)
{
    AppUser user = manager.FindById(iuser.UserId);
    users.Add(user);
}
```

`Professors` remains null for some reason.
Can anybody give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it there is a built in function for this purpose already, but you can get users in this way:

```
public async Task GetUsersInRole()
{
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var roles = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Professor");
    if (roles.Any())
    {
        var users = await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        var result = (from c in users
                       where c.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roles.First().Id)
                       select c);
    }
}
```

And call the method like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    await GetUsersInRole();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I just tried that. And I still keep receiving an empty json array.

Comment: My result on Postman is the following: []. And yep, I just checked the rolename is spelled correctly. I even tried to find it by id, but same thing happening.

Comment: @RottenCheese Are you sure your Role names are "Professor"?

Comment: 100%. That's the exact rolename.

Comment: @RottenCheese Ok. I found what is the problem. It should be `async`. Check my updated answer. It should now works as expected.